# Best practice click jacking prevention: What if javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, clickjacking

I am currently looking into protecting a website against clickjacking. [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) gives the following *best practice* example to do so:

```
<style> html{display : none ; } </style>
<script>
    if( self == top ) {
       document.documentElement.style.display = 'block' ; 
    } else {
       top.location = self.location ; 
    }
</script>
```

I, however, was wondering, what if the client has javascript disabled? Then, he will NOT have the page displayed. We have the requirement to ship a fully functional none-javascript version of the app.

Any recommendation to achieve that?

Comment: These days, you probably can rely on X-Frame-Options alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have guidelines addressing this requirement, including javascript mechanisms to prevent clickjacking :/

Comment: You could use `<script>document.write('<style>html{display:none}</style>');</script>`, but that would defeat the entire purpose of this framebusting approach. You cannot use framebusting scripts without JS enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<script>
    if (self !== top) {
       document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
       top.location = self.location;
    }
</script>
```

to still hide the page in case the navigation attempt is successfully attacked. You could also show a message along the lines of `self.location.href + " cannot be displayed in a frame."` instead.

Of course, this will not prevent your page from being shown in a frame when JavaScript is disabled (maybe not even globally but just in your frame), so you should always send the respective X-Frame-Options header alongside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this from prevent clickjacking :

```
    if (window.top !== window.self) {
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```